# Why are custom fonts set in theme not rendering in the Heading component?

Tags: components, chakra-ui, font-family, heading

Reading and learning Chakra UI and trying to set a default `fontFamily` for the [Heading](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/heading) component I've tried to implement the font I've set in heading:

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    heading: `'Custom Font', sans-serif`,
  },
  styles: {
    global: {
      h1: {
        fontFamily: 'heading',
        color: 'blue',
      },
    },
  },
})

export default theme
```

color changes but the font will not.

---

**Edit** after answer and further research. This seems to be an active [issue](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/3457) unless my approach is incorrect so I will outline everything I've done:

src/theme/index.js:

```
import { extendTheme, theme as defaultTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = extendTheme(
  {
    ...defaultTheme, // Dont think this is needed but was in an answer
    fonts: {
      heading: `'Foo Bar', sans-serif`,
    },
    
  },
)

export default theme
```

Font isn't on [Fontsource](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource) so tried the [`@font-face`](https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts#option-2-using-font-face) approach:

src/theme/Fonts.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Global } from '@emotion/react'

const Fonts = () => (
  <Global
    styles={`
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Foo Bar';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-display: swap;
      src: local('Foo Bar'), url('./fonts/Foo-Bar.woff2') format('woff2');
    }
    `}
  />
)

export default Fonts
```

font is stored in the directory structure:

```
src/theme/fonts/Foo-Bar.woff2
```

Gatsby Wrapper:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

// Theme
import theme from './src/theme'
import Fonts from './src/theme/Fonts'

function RootWrapper({ element }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Fonts /> // <!--- FONTS HERE
      {element}
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

RootWrapper.propTypes = {
  element: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default RootWrapper
```

When I log the theme I can see:

```
fonts: {
  heading: Foo Bar
}
```

Per the answer below when I check `var(--chakra-fonts-heading);` it still shows:

```
--chakra-fonts-heading: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

The only way I can get custom fonts to work is to use `Text` and bring in a `textStyle`:

```
<Text as="h1" textStyle="h1">test</Text>
```

I think this approach dismisses what `Heading` is supposed to be for.

Research:

- [Can't change default fonts in Chakra UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886321/cant-change-default-fonts-in-chakra-ui)
- [How to use ChakraUI extended fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069550/how-to-use-chakraui-extended-fonts)
- [Custom font does not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712393/custom-font-does-not-load)
- [Using fonts in chakra UI in Next js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69387362/using-fonts-in-chakra-ui-in-next-js)
- [Primary and secondary font with Chakra UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70415680/primary-and-secondary-font-with-chakra-ui)
- [Using custom fonts](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/3457)
- [Custom font doesn't work](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui-docs/issues/1586)

dependencies:

```
"@chakra-ui/gatsby-plugin": "^3.1.3",
"@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.0",
"@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
```

why will a custom fonts not render by default but only when passed as a `textStyle`? How can I, by theme default use a heading font for all headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit for additional information provided

I'm suspicious that it could be a cache issue based on previous issues I've seen with Gatsby and running a `gatsby clean` resolving them. I haven't been able to recreate the issue based on what you've provided - the heading font displays for me in multiple configurations with two different fonts, which is why I'm wondering if it's a dev environment anomaly.

I can't pinpoint why specifically it's not working, but I'll share a solution that works for me.

### With Gatsby, @chakra-ui/react, and @chakra-ui/gatsby-plugin:

#### 1. Import local fonts

[Gatsby Using Local Fonts Reference](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/using-local-fonts/)

1. Upload your fonts. I uploaded mine to `src/fonts` in this example. Alternatively to the `static` folder depending on use case.
2. Create a CSS file with @font-face. I created the example in `src/fonts.css`.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url("./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

3. Create/edit `gatsby-browser.js` in the root folder and add this to load the fonts globally. [Gatsby Global Styles](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/)

```js
import "./src/fonts.css"
```

5. Create/edit `gatsby-ssr.js` in root folder to preload your font files. [gatsby-ssr](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/)

```js
import * as React from "react"

export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
    setHeadComponents([
        <link
            rel="preload"
            href="./src/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
            as="font"
            type="font/ttf"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
            key="yourFontKey"
        />,
    ])
}
```

#### 2. Create a [shadow](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/shadowing/) of the Chakra theme file for customizations

[Chakra Gatsby Plugin Reference](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/@chakra-ui/gatsby-plugin/)

1. Create `src/@chakra-ui/gatsby-plugin/theme.js`. The Chakra gatsby-plugin automatically adds the ChakraProvider wrapper, so there's no need to add it separately unless you're doing something custom.
2. Add your customizations. Heading example below:

```js
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = {
   fonts: {
       heading: `'Open Sans', sans-serif`
   }
}

export default extendTheme(theme);
```

### 3. Restart Gatsby server

1. (Optional) `gatsby clean` to clear the cache - this sometimes resolves new/changed font and other display issues.
2. Restart the Gatsby server.

##### [Working sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-cherry-7g6ljr)

---

**Original answer to: Chakra UI theming how to set default fontFamily for Heading component?**

I tried your first code snippet with a custom font and it's working successfully for me.

This is what works for me to import and set font families for the `Heading` component (and any other components that by default use the Chakra 'heading' font):

```js
import {extendTheme} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import '@fontsource-variable/yourFont';

const myTheme = extendTheme({
    fonts: {
        heading: `'yourFont Variable', sans-serif`
    }
})

export default myTheme;
```

---

The [Heading](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/components/heading.ts) component already has the Chakra heading font family applied in their default theme styles (see Heading link above for source code, line 4).

To check if the font is attempting to apply in the browser, select your heading component in dev tools and check if the CSS has `font-family: var(--chakra-fonts-heading);`, which means it's getting the Chakra 'heading' style applied. If that's set and the theme `--chakra-fonts-heading` CSS shows the correct fonts, yet the font is not displaying in the browser, there might be an issue with the font import/render. I've noticed sometimes after I install new fonts I have to stop/start the server for them to pick up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems to be an active issue: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/3457. Going to update question with further attempts

Comment: Also note my font is not stored on `fontsource` so that approach will not work.

Comment: Dont know what it was so I nuked the entire starter and brought in the sandbox and it worked with `woff2` fonts. Nuked `node_modules`, gatsby clean. Think it might have been trying to bring in the provider in gatsby-browser. This completely changes things, so far I've added custom colors, breakpoints, and typography. Now working on components and when I console log the theme it's not dumping everything like it used to just what I've set. Learning `defineStyleConfig` and pre-setting the `Heading` baseStyle but also need to learn how to set a global background color. thanks for the help +1